# Indicadores de trading

Tags: python

Mi pregunta sería, suponiendo que tengo

```
precio1
precio2
precio3
precio4
precio5
precio6
precio7
precio8
precio9
precio10
precio11
precio12
precio13
precio14
```

¿Cómo seria la función para sacar rsi, bollinger band, macd, etc?

Comment: Hola Rafael, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe una librería muy buena que se llama Ta Lib, en la  cual puedes encontrar muy buenos indicadores. Esta es la pagina oficial.

https://www.ta-lib.org/function.html

Para que no tengas problemas en la instalaccion en Windows búscalo en:

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Esto te da varios archivos posibles. Tenes que intentar con cada uno para saber cual es el compatible con tu sistema.

Saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias, gracias a tu respuesta cree un bot de trading, uso linux, me dio un poco de problema la instalacion pero ya esta andando! gracias

Comment: @RafaelHidalgo, me alegro mucho, yo también estoy trabajando en esta parte con poloniex, si quieres déjame tu correo para compartir conocimiento sobre ese tema.

Comment: rafaelhidalgo80@hotmail.com ese es mi correo